Diffusion from an annulus
I'm wondering if the following problem can be solved using the method of images (I'm familiar with how this works for straight boundaries, but not circular boundaries, as in this problem). Suppose we have a sphere of radius $a$ and another sphere of radius $a+L$, both centered at the origin. Let the initial concentration of some substance inside the resulting annulus be $C_0$ and the surface of the inner sphere be a reflecting boundary. In an infinite medium, supposing that concentration changes are governed by diffusion, what is $C(r,t)$? Solving this problem is straightforward if the surface of the inner sphere is not a reflecting boundary, but I'm not sure how to modify the approach of integrating a Green function with the given boundary condition. Any help is appreciated!

If I understand your setup correctly (not sure if it is 2d or 3d) it has spherical symmetry, so it reduces to a 1+1d PDE (which may or may not have an analytical solution). This is probably much more tractable than trying to work with 2d or 3d Green functions adapted to the boundary conditions.

(the "reflective" inner sphere will then simply reduce to the boundary condition $\partial_r C(a, \cdot) \equiv 0$).

For sure -- so would it be correct then to think of the solution as a superposition of the solution to free diffusion from an annulus defined by $a < r < a + L$ and the solution to free diffusion from an annulus defined by $a-L < r < a$? I'm not sure if that is correct use of the method of images.

That won't work, as you can see by checking the conservation of particles – in the $t\to \infty$ limit the superposition of those solutions will have the particles from both annuli in the space outside of the inner sphere, while the number of particles outside of the reflective wall must be conserved in the correct solution.
